# Send data to Broadcast Receiver from MainActivity

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I am trying to send data to my `Broadcast` class using

In my `MainActivity`

```
String stop = "0";
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SMSReceiver.class);
intent.putExtra("label",stop);
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

In my `Broadcast` class

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    Object[] messages = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
    SmsMessage[] sms = new SmsMessage[messages.length];
    final MediaPlayer mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.son1);

    // Creation de messages
    for (int i=0; i < messages.length; i++) {
        sms[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) messages[i]);
    }
    for (SmsMessage msg : sms) {

        // Vérifie
        if (TextUtils.equals(msg.getOriginatingAddress(), ewitnumber)) {
            //Toast.makeText(context, "" + msg.getMessageBody(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent i = new Intent(context, DisplayActivity.class);
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(i);

            String cp = bundle.getString("label");
            Log.d("SMS", ""+cp);

            //music du message
            AudioManager mAudioManager = (AudioManager)context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
            mAudioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, mAudioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC), 0);

            Runnable stopPlayerTask = new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mPlayer.pause();
                }
            };

            if(mPlayer.isPlaying()){
                mPlayer.pause();
            }else{
            mPlayer.seekTo(startime);
            mPlayer.start();
            mPlayer.setLooping(true);
            }
            Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(stopPlayerTask, endtime);

            //Efface le message automatiquement
            abortBroadcast();
        }
    }

}
```

My application crashes.

Comment: Can you post your onReceive method? also have you registered your broadcast receiver in the manifest?

Comment: BTW why are you sending broadcast to the SMSReceiver? Your goal is to simply send the string "label" to the broadcast?

Comment: yes send simply "label" to my broadcast. After sending work, i'll do some operation whith the label

Comment: Hi I posted an answer. Also include the logcat stack trace after your app crashes.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you're receiver is registered in your manifest, it looks like this.

```
<receiver android:name="your.package.SMSReceiver"> 
     <intent-filter> 
          <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" /> 
     </intent-filter> 
     <intent-filter> 
          <action android:name="SMSReceiver.action.label" /> 
     </intent-filter> 
</receiver>
```

When sending broadcast usually I am using intent filter.

```
String stop = "0";
Intent intent = new Intent("SMSReceiver.action.label");
intent.putExtra("label",stop);
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Since your receiver is normally for sms PDU or sms data would normally null and app will crash since your are sending a normal broadcast not a SMS one. So use the intent filter to get the label data.

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    //get the action of the intent
    String action = intent.getAction();

    if(action.equals("SMSReceiver.action.label")){

         String stop = intent.getStringExtra("label");

         //do something

    } else {

        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        Object[] messages = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
        SmsMessage[] sms = new SmsMessage[messages.length];
        final MediaPlayer mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.son1);

        .
        .
        .
        .
        .
    }
}
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Do like this

```
String cp = bundle.getStringExtra("label");
```

and Intent also should be like this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Yourtivity.this, SMSReceiver.class);
```

Comment: Where you wrote this code String cp = bundle.getStringExtra("label"); i did't  find ..any errors ?

Comment: update this in your code Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SMSReceiver.class); instead of my code